# Should options be stored as text or integers in a MySQL DB?

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a small database of names that has three columns: ID, Name, Status

The 'status' can be one of three things: waiting, approved, other

My question is, what is the best/most correct way to store the 'status' in the DB? Should it be stored as a varchar string or as a 1, 2, or 3 integer and later translate that to waiting/approved/other when reading from the DB? I hope that makes sense, thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should have a status table (referred to as a dictionary or lookup table) using a `tinyint` data type to reference that status. You would use a foreign key constraint. This way you maintain relational and domain integrity. It will allow you to add/change/remove status values without changing table structure.

```
status
=============
id  value
1   Waiting
2   Approved
3   Other
```

```
users
====================
id  name   status_id
1   Bobby  3
```

Comment: a seperate table for just 3 constants?

Comment: Allows for more in the future

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say! Also, this method means that you can easily add new statuses should your requirements change in the future.

Comment: @JvdBerg Simply for benefits of maintaining integrity

Comment: Thanks @njk this was really helpful. Would status_id be the foreign key then?

Comment: @Riboflavin You would add a foreign key constraint on `users.status_id` to reference `status.id`.

Comment: @njk sorry if this isn't appropriate to ask here but I am having some trouble understanding the mysql docs, what is the difference between RESTRICT and CASCADE on update/delete and which do you think would be better for this situation?

Comment: @Riboflavin No problem. First, `ON UPDATE/DELETE` just refers to the action. `RESTRICT` means that if you have a user with a `status_id` of 1, and you try to delete that `status_id`, it will restrict you from doing so. You would have to first update those users to a different `status_id`. `CASCADE` means that if you make a change to the `id`, it will *cascade* or update all `status_id` with that `id`. Is this clear?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16808/discussion-between-riboflavin-and-njk)

Answer (score 1):

Create another table called

statuses with 2 fields 
id INT Primary Auto Increment
name varchar(30).

Add your statuses in the user table by integer and reference them with a JOIN.

You can also change status in the users table to status_id it would make more sense.

IMO this is the most appropriate way in

Comment: Thanks Lars :) This helped a lot

Answer (score 0):

Integers are smaller.  Integers can be translated by your app into multiple languages, etc.

Integers good.

Check out [ENUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/enum.html).  If not, make sure you're using the [right sized integer](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html#integer-types).

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, store those items as text, unless:

- You will be searching for them: character searches take longer and are more expensive than numeric (integer) searches
- You will need to do 'math' (summation, averages, standard deviations, etc) on them: casting/converting to a number, performing the calculation and then doing something with the results is very process-intensive)

Answer (score 0):

Use numerics with a separate lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

An integer field uses less memory space than a varchar field, so storing your 'status' option as a number will reduce memory usage marginally.

I recommend storing 'status' in an integer and translating it to the corresponding value externally when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think they should be stored as what they are: a **enum**!

Example:

```
status ENUM('waiting', 'approved', 'other') DEFAULT 'other'
```

Comment: I would recommend reading [8 Reasons Why MySQL's ENUM Data Type Is Evil](http://komlenic.com/244/8-reasons-why-mysqls-enum-data-type-is-evil/).